# When does spring security remember me process the cookie?

Tags: java, cookies, spring-security, remember-me

Spring security 3.1.1

So I made a custom remember me service which extends the default token based remember me service just to check if it's called or not.

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices;

public class CustomTokenBasedRememberMeService extends TokenBasedRememberMeServices {

    @Override
    protected int calculateLoginLifetime(HttpServletRequest request, Authentication authentication) {
        System.out.println("COOKIE: Process1!");
        return super.calculateLoginLifetime(request, authentication);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isTokenExpired(long tokenExpiryTime) {
        System.out.println("COOKIE: Process2!");
        return super.isTokenExpired(tokenExpiryTime);
    }

    @Override
    protected String makeTokenSignature(long tokenExpiryTime, String username, String password) {
        System.out.println("COOKIE: Process3!");
        return super.makeTokenSignature(tokenExpiryTime, username, password);
    }

    @Override
    protected String retrievePassword(Authentication authentication) {
        System.out.println("COOKIE: Process4!");
        return super.retrievePassword(authentication);
    }

    @Override
    protected String retrieveUserName(Authentication authentication) {
        System.out.println("COOKIE: Process5!");
        return super.retrieveUserName(authentication);
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetails processAutoLoginCookie(String[] cookieTokens, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("COOKIE: Process6!");
        return super.processAutoLoginCookie(cookieTokens, request, response);
    }    

    @Override
    public void onLoginSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication successfulAuthentication) {
        System.out.println("COOKIE: Process7!");
        super.onLoginSuccess(request, response, successfulAuthentication);
    }
}
```

when I log in it prints out:

```
INFO: COOKIE: Process7!
INFO: COOKIE: Process5!
INFO: COOKIE: Process4!
INFO: COOKIE: Process1!
INFO: COOKIE: Process3!
```

which means that it calls the onLoginSuccess(), retrieveUserName(), retrievePassword(), calculateLoginLifetime(), and makeTokenSignature().

The browser has accepted the cookie, but it's never processed ever. Even after I deleted the session, restarted the browser, etc. It's never processed, I assume processAutoLoginCookie is responsible for this but it's never called either.

What's the condition for spring security to process the cookie?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you work with TokenBasedRememberMeServices. The processing happens in the **parent**, in **AbstractRememberMeServices**. It happens on its autoLogin() method.

This method is called by RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(). The filter keeps as a member the rememberServices and calls its autoLogin(). So it does not really matter whether you work with PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServicesor with TokenBasedRememberMeServices, the Cookie processing is the same and handled by the parent.

Comment: I could see that if SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()==null then it calls the autoLogin() method
I can't override autoLogin() since it's declared as final. So I trust that it works just fine and I noticed that it calls the processAutoLoginCookie() method afterward. But the method is never called. So I presume either the Authentication is never null or the doFilter() method is never called in the first place. What do you think about this?

Comment: First of all, you can easily debug Spring's code. Then you will be able to see the flow and what happens. Secondly, if you put your logs in "debug", you will see Springs logs (they have one in autoLogin()). This way you will be able to know if autoLogin() was called or not. Note that autoLogin() can be called, but if it does not find the Cookie, it returns null so "processAutoLoginCookie()" will not be called.                             Feel free to mark my answer as good one if it helped :-)

Comment: when will the processAutoLoginCookie method invoked?

Comment: Description copied from class: AbstractRememberMeServices:
**Called from autoLogin** to process the submitted persistent login cookie. Subclasses should validate the cookie and perform any additional management required. 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ui/rememberme/AbstractRememberMeServices.html

Comment: I have implemented token based remember me. In one of the blogs, I read that remember me is invoked once the session is timed out. I have two questions. 1) Whether the cookie token validity time should be set again in remember me? 2) if I refresh from some other page I.e. not login page, would remember me method or auto login be invoked?

Comment: i think it is worth a seperate question here, rather than a comment on another answer....